# UIPickerView pickerView:titleForRow:rowforComponent method not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uipickerviewdatasource, uipickerviewdelegate

I have a UIPickerView in my storyboard.
The UIViewController containing it has interface declarations set

```
@interface ContactDetail : UIViewController <ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
```

on view Load, pickerview delegation set

```
pickerView_RelationshipType.dataSource=self;
pickerView_RelationshipType.delegate = self;
pickerView_RelationshipType.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
```

all UIPickerView datasource and delegate methods are triggered except those 2

```
pickerView:titleForRow:rowforComponent
and
pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView
```

those following are called, no problem

```
    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Comment: thankx to both iBhavin and JAL.
i have realized that my dataSource was returning nil from coreData. problem solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what's in `numberOfComponentsInPickerView` ?

If your `numberOfRows` returning 0, then your delegate method will never be called - the picker won't ask for the title of a row if it doesn't think it has any rows to display.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your data source array is allocated and initialized.  I ran into this problem when everything was hooked up correctly (I set the data source and delegates and was conforming to the protocols), but I forgot to initialize my data source arrays before adding objects to them.  My code was hitting `numberOfComponentsInPickerView` and `numberOfRowsInComponent` but not `titleForRow` and I couldn't figure out why.  Make sure your data source is not returning nil.

Kind of a stupid edge case, but I figured I'd add my answer in case someone else runs into the same issue.